# Why is (one of) the criteria for a Noetherian module not implied by Zorn's lemma?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

One of the equivalent definitions of a Noetherian $R$-module is

> Every nonempty collection of $R$-submodules has a maximal element under inclusion

so, what I'm wondering is, why is this not an immediate application of Zorn's lemma that applies to any module? Our $R$-submodules have a natural partial order under inclusion, and they are bounded above by $M$ because they all must be contained in $M$.

Of course my logic must be wrong somewhere because not every module is Noetherian. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Zorn's lemma** *If every chain in a partially ordered set has an upper bound, then the partially ordered set has a maximal element.*

The condition you are mentioning is about *any* (non empty) collection of submodules having a maximal element. Such collections need not satisfy the condition that every chain has an upper bound, so Zorn's lemma cannot apply.

It's easy to show an example of a partially ordered set (indeed a totally ordered set) that doesn't satisfy the hypothesis of Zorn's lemma, namely the natural numbers under the usual ordering. Note that no infinite subset of the natural numbers has a maximal element.

Turning back to modules, some (non empty) collections of submodules have maximal elements: the finite collections and also all collections containing the module itself.

However, there are examples of module such that *no* infinite set of proper submodules has a maximal element. One of them is the Prüfer $p$-group, where the proper subgroups are linearly ordered just like the natural numbers.

Comment: What's confusing me is, given a collection of submodules, why is $M$ not an upper bound for every chain?

Comment: @AlexMathers The upper bound must belong to the given collection

Comment: WOW all makes sense now. I feel like an idiot.

Comment: I've gone ahead and given you credit for the answer because this explanation made it actually click

Comment: @AlexMathers Don't feel like that! Zorn's lemma is a strange beast that needs to be tamed.

Answer (score 7):

Zorn's lemma tells you that if you consider the set of all submodules, then this set has a maximal element. It does not tell you whether every nonempty collection contains this maximal element, so you cannot conclude that the collection has one.

Now, the collection indeed does have an upper bound (as you've remarked, $ M $ is one such submodule, as it is a submodule of itself) but this upper bound need not be in the collection.

Comment: I see now, thanks

Comment: How does Zorn show that the set of all proper submodules has a maximal element? Any chain of submodules certain has an upper bound - how do you know it has a _proper_ submodule for an upper bound?

Comment: Oops, I typed one word extra there. ("proper") Obviously we don't need Zorn's lemma to show that the set of all submodules has a maximal element, but the point is that using Zorn's lemma doesn't tell us anything different.

Answer (score 2):

Zorn's lemma says that if $X$ is a poset and every chain has an upper bound then $X$ has a maximal element. It does not say that every chain has a maximal element, which is what's relevant here.

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood what you wrote, but it seems to me that the issue here is not the conclusion of Zorn's lemma, but the hypothesis. If $M$ is not Noetherian, there are nonempty collections of $R$-submodules such that not every chain has an upper bound, so Zorn's lemma doesn't apply...

Comment: ??? $M$ is an upper bound for every chain.

Comment: But $M$ isn't contained in every nonempty collection of $R$-submodules.

Comment: I don't see why that matters. Maybe we're talking about totally different things - that could be, given that we're talking about why a certain argument is wrong. The OP says "Our $R$-submodules have a natural partial order under inclusion, and they are bounded above by $M$", hence I assume he's talking about an application of Zorn to that poset. If we're applying Zorn to that poset we need to know that every chain of submodules has an upper bound, period.

Comment: Ok, if otoh we're applying Zorn to an arbitrary collection of submodules then you're exactly right. All I can say is in that case the OP doesn't make much sense...